# How do I connect a table id field to another table id field?

Tags: php, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I'm pretty new to PHP and databases and I'm having some problems creating the database I need.
I'm hoping that someone here can help me! Probably a very stupid question...

What I'm trying to do is create a very simple movie library and creating tables from within phpmyadmin. I have not started writing any PHP code for this yet, I just want to make sure I created the database tables correctly.

I´m doing one table (MOVIES) with the fields: 
ID, TITLE, DIRECTOR, YEAR and CATEGORY_ID.

This table should have a relation to another table for categories. So the CATEGORY_ID field in the first table should be connected to a table that stores the categories.

I have problems with the CATEGORY_ID field. Since the first ID field is set as primary and also Auto indent I can´t have that on the CATEGORY_ID field so when I add movies as a test from within phpmyadmin I just get the Id number 0 on category id.

Just to show the table layout that I've done:

MOVIE TABLE - ID (primary key, auto indent), TITLE, DIRECTOR, YEAR, CATEGORY_ID
CATEGORY TABLE - CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY

Comment: Have you done any reading on foreign key lately?

Comment: Your column names have white spaces like category id. Try using something like category_id for a start. It might save you at the long run. Provide a better database schema. Indent your codes with at least 4 whitespaces when you post them so they get formatted right on StackOverflow. Some basics you might have to learn to get faster results

Comment: Just edit your current question. It might become clearer and easier to work on. Let's see what you've done so far. It could be a good place to start.

Comment: @StewardGodwinJornsen off-topic, but your website seems to be having problems (headers already sent warnings)

Comment: I'm still working on it. Just noticed that today. :) I'd fix that with ob_start()/ob_flush() maybe. Usual problem with host. It wasn't there before. Coming from Codeigniter's session library

Comment: Thinking of an easier way to help Karolina. It's already 11.00pm WAT. I wonder if you could guide him/her format her question right. Seems to be a started, would need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to make a little more study to get complete help. I'd suggest you do some googling and read articles like this one:

http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/

### [EDIT]

Thanks for taking the time to edit your question and making necessary changes:

### Sample Database Schema

**CATEGORY TABLE**

```
CATEGORY_ID int auto_increment (11) (primary key)
CATEGORY
```

**MOVIES TABLE:**

```
ID int auto_increment (Primary Key) 
TITLE, 
DIRECTOR, 
MOVIE_YEAR
CATEGORY_ID int(11) (Foreign Key)
```

Now you see what I mean by a foreign key; The above schema is based on your question and sample. I've only renamed the year column. I'm careful words or names that might conflict with reserved words. I just called it MOVIE_YEAR. TITLE field is not unique. There isn't a need for that. To prevent duplicates if you want, you could query the database for a match. But seeing two movies could have same names, their ids should set them apart.

#### Mysql

You don't need two auto increment columns in a table. Begin by creating category table and loading the values for categories. Id column could be auto increment or not. If it isn't, you'd have to manually provide the ids. Then create the movies table. You are doing a one to many relationship. Meaning, one category could match many movies in the movie table. So having 0 there isn't an error. That issue would be solved by your PHP script. The column is possibly set to not null, so a default value is provided.

#### The PHP Scripting

In PHP, create your code to pull values from category table into something like a dropdown select or clickable links and pass them to a hidden form element. Using a select could be quicker (see example below). The select and other form elements needed to add a new movie would be in one html form. So when you submit the form, it adds the data into the movies table. That data would carry with it the category_id that the user is inserting. This would replace the 0 you now have.

#### Creating the Select Dropdown

0 would happier if you had set the category_id column to not null. Nothing strange. During updates, the same process is repeated. Please note that the select would have a special format as shown below:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connection, $recordset)){ ?>
    <select name='category_id' id='categories_id'>
        <options value='<?php echo $row['category_id'] ?>'><?php echo $row['category_name'] ?></option>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

These value should come from your db and populates the select menu. This should get you started. So try working on the PHP side now with the database you currently have. If you have a PHP code, you could show it so we all tweak it.

***Forget the up and down votes, we're not in a competition in here. It's called reputation. We seem have a lot of it. :)***

#### Displaying Records

Displaying is the tricky part. There you would need a join. Something in the line of:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN category ON movies.category_id = category.id';
$recordset_all = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Something like that would give you all the records on movies and matching records on category. That way, you'd have the category name to work with all movies. And since you don't seem to have column name conflicts, everything should be fine. If you want only matching rows, take out the word LEFT, so movies that don't have category_id matching the foreign key in movies would not be selected.

#### Sub Headings

Your case would get complex if you intend to load rows in subheadings of category names. In which case, you would have to do two database selects and create a function to call and return corresponding movies. There could be a better way. We'd fix that when you come to that part if necessary.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your long answer! It´s been really helpful!I think I´ve been complicating things in my mind a bit. I should give every category like "drama" "thriller" etc a id number by myself right? In my mind I thought it was suppose to be added automatically by the database like the movie ID number is automatically added when a movie is added... This clearifies my problem:)

Comment: Gonna see how it works now! Thanks!

Comment: You have two options, either give them your own ids or let auto increment provide those ids. You could have additional fields outside the auto increment to provide special ids if you want a combination of numbers and strings.

Comment: And don't forget to re-read what I have above. I been updating it since I'm typing on the fly while trying to catch some sleep.

Comment: Sorry now I see what you mean! But if I´m just testing to add a movie in the movie table from within phpmyadmin I need to fill out the category_id number manually right? Once I have written php code and adds a movie from a website I can get it to automatically store the right category_id with the help of "value" code etc...

Comment: Even from phpmyadmin, if the column for id is set to auto increment, leave it blank and the next available auto increment value would be used for that field. Phpmyadmin is built with PHP, it obeys the same rule as what you are about to code. If auto increment, leave blank; if not, provide an id value.

Comment: Well I have auto increment on the regular ID field and then there is the CATEGORY_ID field which has connection to the table CATEGORY. So if just testing to put in a movie in the table within phpmyadmin so if I don´t fill out the CATEGORY_ID field there is only a zero in that field no matter how many movies I´m putting in. So should I not put in the CATEGORY ID manually then instead?

Comment: We are almost at limit here. We might have to switch to chat

Comment: Oops, they said, you can't chat with 1 rep. For manual testing, you'd need to enter a category_id yourself to correspond with any of the ids you have in category table. So first look at the category table and pick and number to use there. Hence, 0 is what the db would put in for you. Also see my edit answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I think I´m getting it now! I will re-read your answers as well! Have a good night sleep! Thanks again!

Comment: If it helps you, just mark it as answered. That's a great addition. And you could come back with questions if you have issues. My eyes are closing but with a few more reps (which you can get easily). We could use chat. That would help you even more.

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE ...
```

more information on table joining can be found [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Remember to prefix your column names with the alias of the table (in this case the aliases are `t1` and `t2`

Hope this helps.

Edit: here is a sample update and select query that you can use to update categoryID and later select using inner join

```
UPDATE MovieTable 
SET categoryID = (number here)
WHERE (use unique identifier like ID or Title if it is unique) = (value)


SELECT my.Title FROM MovieTable mt
INNER JOIN CategoryTable ct ON mt.categoryID = ct.categoryID
WHERE ct.categoryID = (value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: Your welcome. If you want a better example tell me the table name and column you want to connect and ill give you a template

Comment: My problem is in phpmyadmin while creating the tables. When I try and add a movie from phpmyadmin the category id is 0 in table 1. It should be the same as category id in table 2 no?

Comment: Did you set the column to be incremental? Also, you can do an update to set the value equal to the category id you want it to be.

Comment: Sorry, my comments keeps publishing before I´m finished.. I´m wondering if I am doing the fields in the tables wrong? I have one ID field and a CATEGORY ID field in table 1 and then CATEGORY ID field again in table 2. I just don´t understand how I can get the CATEGORY ID number to automatically increase and be the same in both tables.

Comment: I wish you could fix this. I suggest you paste a full code on pastebin and OP can try it. The request requires setting mysql and then writing the php codes to make it work. A faster way might be to see a full code. Not discouraging you but a bit too much for SO

Comment: one thing you can do about this is you can update the movie table to have the category id of the correct category. Then you can have the category table hold all your categories and your movie table can reference then by linking the category id's together via an inner join.

Comment: I have added a better exaple for keeping the id the same and selecting with a join. This can of course should be altered to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have now problems getting the data from the php file to go to the database instead so starting a new thread for that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's is an example of a very common database design of a one-to-many relationship. Notice CATEGORIES has a primary key that is used to relate MOVIES, which employs the FOREIGN KEY statement. Notice also that TITLE must be unique (I am presuming).

```
create table CATEGORIES (
  ID int not null auto_increment,
  Description varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  );
create table MOVIES(
  ID int not null auto_increment,
  TITLE varchar(30),
  DIRECTOR varchar(30),
  YEAR datetime,
  CATEGORY_ID int,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY (TITLE),
  FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORIES(ID)
)
```

Comment: Hello there. In this case require the title of a movie to be unique can be bad. What happens if the movie get remain or a movie with the same name comes out? Just a heads up

Comment: I thought this may be the case, so you should remove the UNIQUE constraint. A database error would be issued if a duplicate TITLE were entered or renamed to an existing one. To avoid a rather cryptic database, the UI would test for duplicates before issuing insert or update commands.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I managed to kind of resolved this issue but off course I got new problems now, so starting a new thread:)